# C# - Simple 2D Graph Plot in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, plot, graph, 2d

I want to plot a value (robot altitude) over time in a simple graph.

I already have the value of the altitude I just cant find a way to plot a 2D graph in my windows forms mainform and which function (altitude in y , time in x) i have to use.

Any help or tools I can use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes there is the System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting namespace. It is a windows forms control, but I use it in WPF in a Windows Forms host, and it works really good.

Chart:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart(v=vs.110).aspx

Tutorial:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489237.aspx

It is included in .NET 4.0+